# Как обновлять картинку в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

У меня стоит задача принимать от Вконтакте ссылку на фото капчи (я ее принимаю, и через `urllib.request.urlretrieve` сохраняю в .jpg

В initUI у меня объявляется pixmap, он суется в label и выводится. В pixmap у меня находится сразу фото старой капчи (еще не обновившееся). Потом пользователь должен нажать на кнопку, далее вк отправляет мне капчу, я ее сохраняю и пользователю должна она по идее вывестись с этим кодом:

```
data = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, r"Путь")
self.pixmap = QPixmap(r"Путь")
self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
```

Но у меня просто зависает программа и ничего не происходит, что делать? Может нужно использовать не setPixmap, а какую то другую функцию, которая будет не создавать pixmap для label, а обновлять его

Comment: Все работает в pyqt с обновление лейбла правильно, ппросто у меня в другом ошибка была

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, вы решили свой вопрос? Как понимать: `Все работает в pyqt...` и `не работает, также зависает и все`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def on_click(self):
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(some_url).read()
    pixmap = QPixmap()
    pixmap.loadFromData(data)
    self.lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Comment: не работает, также зависает и все